# SQLAlchemy multiple extract in hybrid property expressions

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a table with a `Column(Date)` and i want to filter queries with a tuple `(month, day)`, like this:

```
ses.query(MyTable).filter_by(month_day=(3, 25))
```

So inside my table i created an hybrid property:

```
class DataLine(Base):
    # ....

    @hybrid_property
    def date_month_day(self):  # this is working for output
        return self.date.month, self.date.day

    @date_month_day.expression
    def date_month_day(self):  # does not work for querying
        # return always empty results
        return extract('month', DataLine.date), extract('day', DataLine.date)
```

I don't want to separate the properties between a month and day, how to make it work with a tuple an input ? Is it even possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is, using the [`tuple_()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.tuple_) construct in your hybrid property expression:

```
@date_month_day.expression
def date_month_day(self):
    return tuple_(extract('month', DataLine.date), extract('day', DataLine.date))
```

The reason why it did not work before was that since your expression returned a plain Python `tuple`, the comparison took place in Python yielding `False`. In other words you effectively had

```
filter(False)
```